# Is it possible to simulate copy and paste and clicks on a website using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

There's an extension for Google Chrome that automatically parses some data, copy it and paste it in a predefined area of a website, clicking on links etc to get to the right place. (I'm not talking about iMacro).

As far as I know, chrome extensions are written in Javascript.

I want to be able to run a javascript that does this job for me, without needing the chrome extension.

Is it possible to do something like this using javascript?

Comment: No. It'd be a huge browser security risk.

Comment: The reason this works in Google Chrome as a plugin is that you can interface with the browser which allows you to take advantage of functionality not available to javascript. Also, flash, just like every other JS plugin.